# Is it possible to listen/intercept LSP messages to/from typescript language server in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

Our extension refers (has links) to typescript symbols. That's why, I should know whenever a symbol is refactored/renamed, to reflect the name changes in my extension. Is it possible? If yes, how?

AFAIK, I could listen to `textDocument/rename` request of the typescript extension, but how can I do it?

If you think about it, simply listening to code changes won't give you much, because a user can completely replace a symbol with some absolutely other kind and type of symbol, or the user can move the symbol back and forth etc. On the other hand, refactoring a symbol is completely deterministic, i.e. you absolutely sure that only the name has changed, not the position, not the symbol itself etc.

P.S. I've asked a similar question before, but the subjects and what I am really asking are completely different.

Comment: There isn't even a TypeScript language server in VSCode by default. The built-in TS support is coded directly against the VSCode API. See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/a426717b50d68810ddfbf55558d777852bc21db0/extensions/typescript-language-features/src/features

Comment: @Gama11 Wow, didn't know things are even worse than I thought. Thank you! BTW I am trying to solve my task with a typescript language service plugin...

Comment: @Nurbol I have very similar needs: 1. getting notifications on rename refactor events 2. send such events for myself. Do you have an avaliable solution I can learn from or can you please share your thoughts how to approach the problem?

Comment: @PEZO If I recall correctly, I ended up re-parsing the whole file on every code change.